# How does Murmurhash3_x86_128 work for data larger than 15 bytes?

Tags: c++, c, hash, murmurhash

I want to use MurmurHash3 in a deduplication system with no adversary. So Murmurhash3 will hash files, for instance.

However I am having problems using it, meaning I am doing something wrong.

Murmurhash3_x86_128() [(source-code)](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/source/browse/trunk/MurmurHash3.cpp) function receives four parameters. This is my understanding of what they are:

**key** - input data to hash

**len** - data length

**seed** -  seed

**out** - computed hash value

When running it fails with segmentation faults, because of this part of the code:

```
    void MurmurHash3_x86_128 ( const void * key, const uint32_t len,
                               uint32_t seed, void * out )
    {
     const uint8_t * data = (const uint8_t*)key;
     const uint32_t nblocks = len / 16;
     ...

     const uint32_t * blocks = (const uint32_t *)(data + nblocks*16);

     for(i = -nblocks; i; i++)
     {
            uint32_t k1 = blocks[i*4];
            ...
     }
     ...
    }
```

So if my data has length greater than 15 bytes (which is the case), this *for loop* is executed. However, *blocks* is pointed to the end of my data array and then it starts accessing memory positions after that position. The segmentation faults are explained. So *key* can't be just my data array.

My question is: What should I put in *key* parameter?

---

**Problem Solved**

After the answer of Mats Petersson I realized my code had a bug. i must be an int (signed) and I had it unsigned. That is the reason why it was adding memory positions to blocks and not subtracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blocks` points at the last even multiple of 16 bytes in the block being calculated.

`i` starts at -nblocks, and is always less than zero (loop ends at zero).

So, say you have 64 bytes of data, then the pointer `blocks` will point at `data + 64` bytes, and `nblocks` will be `4`.

WHen we get to `k1 = blocks[i*4];` the first time, `i = -4`, so wer get index `-16` - which is multiplied by the `sizeof(*blocks)`, that is 4 (int = 4 bytes in most architectures) - so we get `-64` = start address of `data`.

Comment: Now I understand! 
I had to adapt the cpp version to c, and I switched i from int to uint, by mistake. That's why it was adding memory positions and not subtracting! 

Thanks!!